# T-SQL Pattern Match/Regex 0 or 1 occurrences of square bracket

Tags: t-sql, escaping, sql-like, brackets, square

I've been trying to match, using LIKE or PATINDEX where a string of format

[subdomain.domain.com].[dbo].[MyDatabase]

occurs in a SQL string

While the string [subdomain.domain.com] will always appear in this format

the [dbo] and/or [MyDatabase] may appear with or without the square brackets

I have tried the following

WHERE SQLString LIKE '%[[]subdomain.domain.com[]].[[]{0,1}dbo[]]{0,1}.[[]{0,1}MyDatabase[]]{0,1}%'

or

WHERE SQLString LIKE '%\[subdomain.domain.com\].\[{0,1}dbo\]{0,1}.\[{0,1}MyDatabase\]{0,1}%' ESCAPE '\'

I could create multiple WHERE OR WHERE statements, covering each possiblity, but would like to understand why the regex isn't working, in this case.

Comment: Are you using SQL Server? If so, what version?

Comment: [`Like`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) <> [RegEx](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247). What made you think they were equivalent?

Comment: @JakeMc the it's SQL Server 2012 SP4 v 11.07493.4

Comment: @HABO not sure I understand. I understand regular expression/pattern matching constructs can be used in a LIKE statement. Not sure I was implying equivalence?

Comment: Elements like `{0,1}` don't appear to be documented for `like` [patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#arguments). What is your source for documentation that includes that syntax in `like` patterns?

Comment: @HABO True, it appears I conflated more than one source, and came up with an invalid solution, I will have to stick with multiple where clause, or "greedy" solution as suggested by Jake. Thnaks for your input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [square bracket](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is a special character in the `like` clause, that means "Any single character within the specified range (for example [a-z])."

You could just use the `%` special character wherever there *might* be a square bracket in your text. Something like:

```
WHERE SQLString LIKE '%subdomain.domain.com%.%dbo%.%MyDatabase%'
```

Since that will match "Any string of *zero* or more characters", if there is a square bracket there, great, if not, it still matches.

Comment: Thanks for getting back Jake, though I have tried that. It is a little "greedy" and would pick up e.g. "subdomain.domain.com lots of text AnotherDatabase.dbo.table lots more text MyDatabase.dbo.Mytable". I am hoping to match those specific patterns. it seems the {0,1} modifier may not be applicable to tsql

Comment: HI Jake, the square brackets are also used to escape, though it looks like I have been over  zealous, in the first example I provided, it seems the escaping is not required for the closing square bracket.

Comment: @Matt I believe you would need to define one of the square brackets as the escape_character explicitly using the [ESCAPE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#pattern-matching-with-the-escape-clause) keyword at the end of the Like clause for it to be used as the escape_character. For that matter, you could define any single character, perhaps one that would be more readable to the next developer who will see the query. Also try using the `_` instead of `%` where there may be brackets since underscore matches a single char